# ASP.Net Core - Application Parts - prevent loading assemblies into app domain

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, appdomain

I have a web app with several dependencies (modules) that should be loaded dynamically based on config. For some reason ASP.Net Core adds some of these dependencies as ApplicationParts and loads these assemblies into app domain. Even if I remove these assemblies from `ApplicationParts` list they are still a part of app domain and cannot be unloaded. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'should be loaded dynamically'? If ASP.NET Core adds them as app parts then apparently they are referenced and therefore loaded. Moreover, adding them as app parts mean the controllers. view components, tag helpers are discovered (which cannot happen if they are not loaded).

Comment: @AlexanderChristov I mean that there's a code that loads an assembly (using `Assembly.Load`) based on appsettings.json. The problem is that after `services.AddMvc` even unused assemblies are loaded just because they are inside `bin` folder. So, before this method `AppDomain.GetAssemblies` gives a smaller list of assemblies and after that it shows that several extra assemblies were loaded. Not just ASP.Net Core assemblies but my custom assemblies that shouldn't be loaded all at once

Comment: So, use a dedicated, say, 'Modules' folder. It may, for example, may be inside your app root folder. This will allow for finer control over what's loaded and why.

Comment: Yes, that's an option, though in this case I'll need some post-build step to move the assemblies out of bin folder

Answer (score -2):

You can remove ApplicationParts using below code, Please give a try and let me know.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(o =>
        {
            o.ApplicationParts.Clear();
            o.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
        });
}
```

Comment: No, as I said, even if I remove these assemblies from ApplicationParts list they are still a part of app domain and cannot be unloaded

Comment: @Random can you please put the code, you are using?